# Typo3: page.999 >

Tags: typo3

I'm sure there's a quick answer but I just cannot find it. Search engines don't get me any results when I put ">" or "greater than" and I've also searched the typoscript reference. I need to know what `page.999 >` does in a root template?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the object unsetting operator, see the [TypoScript syntax documentation](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptSyntaxReference/8.7/Syntax/TypoScriptSyntax/Index.html#object-unsetting-the-sign):

> This is used to unset an object and all of its properties.

Comment: damn I forgot that those signs are called operators in any language ... "typoscript operators" would have gotten me to the right results. thanks

Answer (score 2):

Well let's just say you have a CSS file that is coming from an Extension. Let's take the tx_news as example.

The tx_news, if you include the static template, gives you a CSS file on the header area of your html with the name news-basic.css. If you want to keep the static template in and remove the CSS file, this is the operator you use. "`>`"

For example:

```
plugin.tx_news.settings.cssFile >
```

At this point you say "Please remove the CSS file, i do not need it". Whatever the setting cssFiles holds, just remove it.

The same happens to you page.999. The page.999 holds something in it. With the "**>**" operator, you remove it. (at least in frontend).

On the other hand, if you use the "`=`" operator, you define a new file. Like this:

```
plugin.tx_news.settings.cssFile = EXT:myExtension/Resources/News/Resources/Public/Css/news.css
```

And with this operator `<` you append something on the cssFile

```
plugin.tx_news.settings.cssFile < lib.pathToTheFile
```

Best regards,